# ErrorException Undefined array key 0 (View: C:\Users\Teacher\CNHSSystem\resources\views\section\index.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

Hello everyone I was trying to pass value from my resource section blade

```
<form action="POST" action="{{ ('/import-students') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @foreach($programs as $program)
                                  @if($section->program_id == $program->id)
                                    <input type="hidden" name="strand" value="{{ $program->strand }}">
                                  @endif
                                @endforeach
                                <input type="hidden" name="section" value="{{ $section->section_name }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="grade_level" value="{{ $section->grade_level }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="semester" value="{{ $section->semester }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="school_year" value="{{ $section->school_year }}">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" name="submit">
                              add
                            </button>
                            <!-- <input type="submit" class="text-primary" name="submit"> -->
                        </form>
```

to an import blade from another resource

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ ('/upload-students') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="strand" value="{{ request('strand') }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="section" value="{{ request('section') }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="grade_level" value="{{ request('grade_level') }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="semester" value="{{ request('semester') }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="school_year" value="{{ request('school_year') }}">
                <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-1">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

the problem is that the **action** from the section blade doesn't seem to read the controller

```
public function importStudents(Request $request)
    {
        // dd($request);

        $strand = $request->input('strand');
        $section = $request->input('section');
        $grade_level = $request->input('grade_level');
        $semester = $request->input('semester');
        $school_year = $request->input('school_year');
        

        return view('student.import', $strand, $section, $grade_level, $semester, $school_year);
    }
```

Here's my **web** route

```
Route::post('/import-students', [StudentController::class, 'importStudents']);
```

I'am hoping for your help maam/sirs
and a very big THANK YOU in advance for the help that I can receive maam/sirs.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, correct forms:

```
<form action="POST" action="{{ ('/import-students') }}">
```

this form has two `action` (method="post" not action) etc. Open this page: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#forms and see how to write it correctly.

**Second**, in `view('view', $data)` the second parameter should contain data (https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views). So:

```
return view('student.import', [
            'strand' => $strand,
            'section' => $section,
            'grade_level' => $grade_level,
            'semester' => $semester,
            'school_year' => $school_year
]);
```